# Disable WPML translations on /wp-admin (serialize and deserialize increases page load time)

Tags: php, wordpress, serialization, deserialization, wpml

We use WPML plugin for WordPress. We would like it to be disabled when we access /wp-admin. Is this possible at all?

Furthermore, we've noticed an increase in page load time when a lot of content is present (due to the serialize and deserialize) so this makes the wp-admin interface unbearably slow.

Does anybody know how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try do do this:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'disable_wpml_for_admin');    
function disable_wpml_for_admin() {
    if (is_admin()) {
        // don't forget to do for the same way for all wpml extensions
        deactivate_plugins(
            array(
                '/wpml-translation-management/plugin.php'
            ),
            true, // silent mode (no deactivation hooks fired)
            false // network wide
        );
    }
}
```

It based on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159085/deactivate-plugin-for-a-specific-user-group

I wanted to put `get_current_screen()` function to check that we are in admin area, but description told us that it not defined on all admin pages and in some cases you will get error, that's why I check only `is_admin()` — but it's mean that until you legged as admin even you are on client side — WPML will not work for you.

Comment: Thanks! This would essentially mean the admin would have to logout to see the content and translations and would be completely unable to switch languages if needed. 

I just want it not to perform or attempt any translations while logged in but still have the plugin enabled if that makes sense?

For example, in the current situation when the default language is set to English. It still performs a serialize and deserialize to check for translations and we have to wait during page load on wp-admin for this to happen thus increasing the page load of everything that happens within wp-admin.

Comment: It should disable this plugin for admin when he logged in, that's mean it should also consider about not to run serialize and deserialize because they run from WPML plugin and it's disabled, but need to test for sure.